# Global variables objective-C not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, global-variables, extern

I need to create global variables in a class1, which will hold some coordinates, which I then want to use in a different class2. These variables are used and changed in a method in class1, I then need to call them in class2 after being used by the method in class1. My research has taken me to the “extern” definition but I’m not quite sure of how to get the value of these global variables in class 2. Any example code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FWIW globals are generally considered a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Create header and source file GlobalVariable.h and GlobalVariable.m

In GlobalVariable.h declare global variable like this:
extern NSString * globalString;

In GlobalVariable.m put default value like this:
NSString* globalString = @"global_string";

Put #import "GlobalVariable.h" in files where you want to use global variables, and you can access them like they are local variables.